# Is it possible to view videos with Amazon Fire Stick using a wireless connection?

Tags: networking, usb, video, hdmi, vlc

Here goes my enquiry:

I would like to watch videos on TV using a wireless network and the Amazon Fire TV Stick. I have the 20.04.1 LTS version of Ubuntu installed, and I use the VLC media player to watch videos on my computer.

After doing some search, I haven't found a way that enables Ubuntu users to connect their computer with Amazon Fire TV Stick. This makes me think it is not possible yet. Is this correct, or do you know a way to do so? Is it possible I need to buy a specific adaptor to connect the computer with the Fire Stick?

Any feedback will be highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. That version of Ubuntu is beyond EOL and off topic on this site. Sorry.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I'd suggest checking your facts as Ubuntu 21.04 was **not** a LTS release with no point release (*updated ISO*) released thus. 21.04.1 makes no sense (*it doesn't exist*)

Comment: If the 21 was a typo, VLC should be able to cast to the fire stick.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Version is 20.04.1 LTS. @crip659, you say it is possible to couple VLC with the Fire Stick?

Comment: Will look into it, thank you.

Comment: Google says so, don't use fire stick myself.  Do find chromecast plus videostreamer is the best on my computer for casting videos.  Casts many video formats without heavy cpu use.  Chromecast does seem to need an android device just for first setup.

Comment: So I have to buy this chromecast device which costs almost $30 in Amazon... I think I'm going to try first to connect the laptop and the TV with an HDMI cable and see if it works. Thank you anyway.